# Does not connect to the Internet via VPN. Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: networking, 15.04, network-manager, vpn

Installed 15.04 Ubuntu, connection to the Internet via VPN working normally. After restarting I can not even click on VPN connection sign as if it's doesn't exist. At the same time in the guest session clicks and connects normally. What could be the reason, how to fix this issue,tell me please?